# No message body reader has been found for class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, ContentType: multipart/form-data

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey

I have a jersey server and client. I have tried almost everything but I can not send a file from client to server. I am using this method from server side:

```
@Path("/" + PathConstants.UPLOAD_RESOURCE)
public class UploadResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream 
         uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
         String uploadedFileLocation = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\" + 
         fileDetail.getFileName();
         System.out.println(uploadedFileLocation);
         File objFile = new File(uploadedFileLocation);
         if (objFile.exists()) {
            objFile.delete();

        }

        saveToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
        String output = "File uploaded via Jersey based RESTFul Webservice to: " 
        + uploadedFileLocation;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
private void saveToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = null;
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

my server pom.xml dependencies:

```
      <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

my server web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>test</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>server-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.server</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>server-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

    Client side code:

    @Override
    public void execute(CommandArgument arguments) {
    File file = new File("C:\\addfile.txt");
    final ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    final Client client = Client.create(config);
    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
    client.addFilter(
            new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(CommandLineRestClient.currentUsername, 
    CommandLineRestClient.currentPassword));
    WebResource resource = client.resource(PathConstants.UPLOAD_FILE);
    FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
    ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class,
            formDataMultiPart);
    System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatus());
}
```

and my client dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the stack trace :

```
     WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported 
Media Type
at 
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody
(JAXRSUtils.java:1315)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter
(JAXRSUtils.java:826)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters
(JAXRSUtils.java:789)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest
(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:212)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage
(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
```

Could anyone tell me where I am wrong because I am trying to figure this out for a few days, and I still can not make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're on the right way with your back-end code. Get rude of unnecessary stuff in "consumes". You need only multipart-form-data here.

```
@Consumes( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
```

My suspicion is that the problem is on the clients-side or with dependencies.
So the client for that should look like this:

```
public void testUploading() {
        File file = new File("C:\\your_test_file_to_upload.jpg");
        FileDataBodyPart fileDataPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
        try (FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()) {
                MultiPart multipartEntity = formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(fileDataPart);

                Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();

                Response response = client.target("/" + PathConstants.UPLOAD_RESOURCE)
                        .request()
                        .post(Entity.entity(multipartEntity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
        }
}
```

Check that the MultiPartFeature registered on the server & client (I did it for you in the example) both.
Also, it looks like you're on legacy Jersey, consider update to [jersey-media-multipart](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Really appreciate it! So just to make sure I understand you correct, you are suggesting to use org.glassfish instead of com.sun jersey dependencies?

Comment: My suggestions:
1) Remove unnecessary Media types in @Consumes
2) Check that MultiPart feature registered for the server and client sides
3) Move to org.glassfish jars instead of com.sun
Mentioned exception usually thrown when the feature is not registered or no suitable handler for the media type present. In the second case you need to place correct jar. Unfortunately Jersey site is down now, so I can't point you to the correct jar for your version. That's why I recommend to upgrade.

Comment: I am using HTTP basic authentication and if I use this Client that you mentioned how would I send the authentication header. Have a look at my client side code for sending file:

Comment: And how can  I register MultiPartFeature ?

Comment: Multipart registration for client       
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
/////
Server registration depends on how you create your application. For example, if you're extending ResourceConfig you able to do it like this:

public class YourWebApp extends ResourceConfig {
       public YourWebApp() {
                     register(MultiPartFeature.class);
       }
}

Answer (score 0):

I also forgot to mention my client side code in which I am using HttpBasicAuthentication so the server can authenticate user who is sending the request If I modify the client to the version that you suggest how can I authenticate user. Have a look at the client side code :

```
public class UploadCommand implements Command {

@Override
public void execute(CommandArgument arguments) {
    File file = new File("C:\\addfile.txt");
    final ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    final Client client = Client.create(config);
    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
    client.addFilter(
            new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(CommandLineRestClient.currentUsername, CommandLineRestClient.currentPassword));
    WebResource resource = client.resource(PathConstants.UPLOAD_FILE);
    FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
    ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class,
            formDataMultiPart);
    System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatus());
}
```

Comment: Basic authentication should work like this    
HttpAuthenticationFeature authFeature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("username", "password");
client.register(authFeature);